# Content Binding not working for Text block when I used it in Treeview Item

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a Tree View, I am using a Text block inside my Tree view Item.I can not able to bind text for text block When I used "Data context" for my Treeview Item. Can any one help me in fixing this Issue.

```
 here is my xaml code..

<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding XYZ}">
     <TreeViewItem.Header>
          <StackPanel>
             <Image Source="abc.png" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding BindContent}"></TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
     </TreeViewItem.Header>
</TreeViewItem>

 in My View Model, I am using  

private string _content;
   public string BindContent
   {
     get{ return _content;}
     set{_content= value;}
   }

In my constructor I am setting value for Content...
```

It is working fine when I used static content (or) when I am not using 
Data context for Treeview Item. but for some other reasons i need to use Data Context.
 How can I bind Content for Text block When I used Data Context for Tree view Item...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: take a look a the VS output window. You will find precise binding errors pointing to the exact problem there.

Comment: Also what is the reason for using ItemsSource for TreeViewItem? You should set it for TreeView

Comment: What is `XYZ`? Does your property `BindContent` lies in the class of type XYZ?

Comment: @HighCore : Thanks for suggestion, Will Look in to that...

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli - Thanks for your reply, I am using Item source for Tree view Item because I have 2 Tree view Items in Tree view. For First Item I am binding "XYZ" Property and for the other Treeview Item I am binding some other Property.. So I am using Item source for each Tree view item instead of using it for Tree view..

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem could be that you are not implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or you are not raising the notify property changed event. By default the text is null, then you set it in your `ViewModel`'s constructor, but if it is not `INotifyPropertyChanged` then the view will not be notified.

Hope this could helps you to solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can do,

Make sure your viewmodel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` as suggested by Raul Otario and you raise the event on property change,

Secondly, you can use relative source in your binding something like, UserControl if your xaml is on usercontrol else Window

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.BindContent, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

Hope it helps...